# Poll Listing, Where admin can rate and user and rate a poll?

Tags: 7, polls, rating

I need to develop a page, where we need to display a list of polls which are published.

and

Need to create a content by admin where user and admin, both can rate it.

Does anybody suggest a contributed module or Do i need create custom Module for it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Advanced Poll Module](https://drupal.org/project/advpoll).

> > Advanced Poll is a replacement to Drupal's poll module and provides multiple voting systems, decision-making tools, and management options.

For more details you could go through the README.txt of this module.